# How does DocuSign work with WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, docusignapi

I have an **e-commerce** website and now I want to integrate the **DocuSign** with it. The purpose is everyone has to sign the digital document before placing the order. I have used **WooCommerce** plugin for the shop page. So how to integrate the `DocuSign API` with **WooCommerce**?

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign has a REST API that has the same functionality that they have on their website. You could call the REST API programmatically from your WordPress code and you should be able to send envelopes, get their status and do a lot more.

The documentation of the REST API is here https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api

They also have a GitHub repo with some sample PHP code that you could use: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-php-client